# Toggling data in database

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am trying to toggle a switch to set my database status to either a 0 or 1. I am using an ajax request but nothing happens when i try toggle. What am i not doing right?

I have included an update but nothing happens and there no errors in my console as well. Am i doing the right thing?

**Controller**

```
 public function updateFlag()
    {
        if(Request::ajax())
        {
            $auto_reply = Toggle::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
            if($auto_reply->status == 0)
            {
                $auto_reply->status = 1;

                $auto_reply->save();
            }

            else{
                    $auto_reply->status = 0;

                    $auto_reply->save();
                }
        }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container ">
    <input checked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Enabled" data-off="Disabled"  name="auto_reply" type="checkbox">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
$("[name='auto_reply']").bootstrapSwitch();
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("[name='auto_reply']").on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch',function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/admin/dashboard/status/update',
                    method: 'post',
                    success: function(data){
                        alert("Auto Reply has been Turned On");
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert("Auto Reply has failed");

                    }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('admin/dashboard/status/update', 'StatusController@updateFlag');
```

**Update**

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("[name='auto_reply']").on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch',function(){

                $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/admin/dashboard/status/update',
                    method: 'post',
                    success: function(data){
                    alert("Auto Reply has been Turned: "+data.msg);
                    },
                    error: function(){
                    alert("Auto Reply has failed");

                    }
                 });
            });
        });
</script>
```

**Error log**

[

```
    2017-11-19 19:48:23] local.ERROR: Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::ajax() should not be called statically {"userId":1,"email":"data@gmail.com","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Non-static method Illuminate\\Http\\Request::ajax() should not be called statically at /Users/emmnock/FastFoodOderSystem/app/Http/Controllers/Admin/LoyaltyController.php:70)
    [stacktrace]
    #0 /Users/emmnock/FastFoodOderSystem/app/Http/Controllers/Admin/LoyaltyController.php(70): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(8192, 'Non-static meth...', '/Users/emmnock/...', 70, Array)
    #1 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\Admin\\LoyaltyController->updateFlag()
    #2 /Users/emmnock/FastFoodOderSystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #3 /Users/emmnock/FastFoodOderSystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/R

outing/ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('updateFlag', Array)
```

Comment: do you really have a model Toggle in your app?

Comment: @lewis4u  yes i have

Comment: What a model Toggle has from properties? I mean the table columns?

Comment: Tail the laravel request  / database log to see the actual request

Comment: So there is no table toggles?

Comment: I have a table called toggles @lewis4u

Comment: Sorry but this is an anti pattern for me. Never seen something like this before... Is Toggle model related to some other model?

Comment: @CodyCaughlan  check my update. the error log

Comment: it's because you call it like this `if(Request::ajax())` instead of this `request()->ajax()`

Comment: yes it is related to other models. Look at my error update @lewis4u

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159348/discussion-between-lewis4u-and-switz).

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
public function updateFlag(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax())
        {
            $auto_reply = Toggle::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
            if($auto_reply->status == 0)
            {
                $auto_reply->status = 1;

                $auto_reply->save();
            }

            else{
                    $auto_reply->status = 0;

                    $auto_reply->save();
                }
        }
    }
```